# Displaying only service name NSD network service discovery Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nsd

I have this question again about NSD, this time I would like to ask ask if anybody know how to display only service name without all the details like port, host, service type.So far I managed to display all services using ArrayList and NsdServiceInfo object which displays all details about service as I mentioned before, but in my case I want to display only service name.

If you have any ideas, you are more than welcome to share with me

```
private String SERVICE_TYPE = "_lala._tcp.";

private InetAddress hostAddress;
private int hostPort;
private NsdManager mNsdManager;
NsdServiceInfo mService;

private WebView mWebView;
ArrayList<NsdServiceInfo> services;
ArrayAdapter<NsdServiceInfo> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Getting toolbar by id
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //disabling default title text
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //NSD stuff

    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);


    //Creating the arrayList and arrayAdapter to store services
    services = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, services);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.ListViewServices);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //Creating onClick listener for the chosen service and trying to resolve it

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Object serviceObj = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            NsdServiceInfo selectedService = (NsdServiceInfo) serviceObj;
            //mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
            mNsdManager.resolveService(selectedService, mResolveListener);

        }
    });


}

// Each time create new discovery listener for discovery methods onServicefound.

NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
        Log.e("TAG", "DiscoveryFailed: Error code: " + errorCode);
        mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Discovery failed : Error code: " + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service discovery started");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);

    }

    // When service is found add it to the array. Log d is for debugging purposes.
    @Override
    public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {




        Log.d("TAG", "Service discovery success : " + serviceInfo);
        Log.d("TAG", "Host = " + serviceInfo.getServiceName());
        Log.d("TAG", "Port = " + serviceInfo.getPort());
        services.add(serviceInfo);


        //Notifying adapter about change in UI thread because it informs view about data change.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

    }

    //When service connection is lost to avoid duplicating we create new serviceToRemove object and check if that object is equals to current service,
    // if it yes wre remove the service from an array and inform adapter about the change.

    @Override
    public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service lost " + nsdServiceInfo);
        NsdServiceInfo serviceToRemove = new NsdServiceInfo();
        for (NsdServiceInfo currentService : services) {
            if (currentService.getHost() == nsdServiceInfo.getHost() && currentService.getPort() == currentService.getPort() && currentService.getServiceName() == currentService.getServiceName()) {
                serviceToRemove = currentService;
            }
        }
        if (serviceToRemove != null) {
            services.remove(serviceToRemove);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Xd" + services);
    }
    //}
};

//Creating new Resolve listener each time when user chooses the service. If the connection was made we launch web view activity with the webpage.

NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {


    @Override
    public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int errorCode) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Resolved failed " + errorCode);
        Log.e("TAG", "Service = " + nsdServiceInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {


        Log.d("TAG", "bbz" + nsdServiceInfo);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Log.d("TAG", "Resolve Succeeded " + nsdServiceInfo);

        if (nsdServiceInfo.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Same IP");
            return;
        }


        hostPort = nsdServiceInfo.getPort();
        hostAddress = nsdServiceInfo.getHost();


    }
};


// NsdHelper's tearDown method
public void tearDown() {

    mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);

}


}
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` displays the return from `toString()` called on its data type, so what you're seeing is `NsdServiceInfo#toString()`. If you want just the name, you could change your `ArrayList` and `ArrayAdapter` to a `<String>` type parameter, and build the list with `serviceInfo.getServiceName()`, instead of `serviceInfo`. Or you could create a simple wrapper type around `NsdServiceInfo` that returns the name from a `toString()` override. Or you could do a custom `Adapter`, and handle setting whatever you like in `getView()`.

Comment: I tried to do <String> with serficeInfo.getServiceName() but it does not work, it throws me an error that nsdServiceInfo can not CAST to string.

Comment: In `onItemClick()`, I'm assuming? Yeah, you're going to have to modify other parts of your code, no matter which option you choose. The easiest one, though, is probably the last. For that, you could go back to what you had for the `List` – i.e., `ArrayList<NsdServiceInfo>` – and use this `Adapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter<NsdServiceInfo>`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10x3b8hS1657dO2Oyoa9In_pp_Vo_USP7/view?usp=drivesdk. It's a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Thank you, I created new java class with NsdInfoAdapter and extracted the service name, it worked, but with that came different issue.  Now some of the service names takes other services names from that list and displays same names on the screen  , but in the log I can see that behind  they are still have their own names, do you have any idea why is that  ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure what you're saying. Do you mean you're getting duplicate service names in the `ListView`? Did you use the `Adapter` I'd given above?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining well, but yes my service names duplicate and yes, I used yours adapter I modified a bit following  this tutorial https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd

Comment: Hmm, I can't be sure without seeing your current code.